# Need something like a finished-signal from QWidget

Tags: qt, signals, qwidget

I'm searching for something like the finished-signal from `QDialog`, only for `QWidget`. The reason is, I disable my toolbar once the widget pops up (which isn't a problem at all) and I want the toolbar to be enabled again, once the widget is closed.

I also can't override the close-Event of that widget, because then we would have GUI-code in business-classes.

Comment: Emit a signal from the widget? Or catch `destroyed()` signal?

Comment: Your last line doesn't really make sense. A widget is a GUI item, its close event is GUI code. Why would overriding that cause a mix of GUI & business logic?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the widget to be deleted on close, and then listen to its `destroyed` signal:

```
widget->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
connect( widget, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), this, SLOT(widgetDestroyed(QObject*)) );
```

That only works if you're not interested in the widget contents though. At the point `destroyed()` is emitted, the widget isn't a `QWidget` anymore, just a `QObject` (as `destroyed()` is emitted from `~QObject`), so you can't cast the argument `QObject*` to `QWidget` anymore.

A simple alternative might be to wrap your widget with a `QDialog`.

Comment: Hi Frank, how do I implement the `widgetDestroyed` slot?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do when the widget is destroyed, there's no generic answer what to do in the slot.

Answer (score 15):

In your Widget class, you can add your own signal that others can connect to.  Then override the `closeEvent()` method.  Don't worry about overriding this method, this kind of situation is exactly the right reason do to it.

```
class MyCustomWidget: public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT

    ...

    signals:
       void WidgetClosed();

   protected:

     //===============================================================
     // Summary: Overrides the Widget close event
     //  Allows local processing before the window is allowed to close.
     //===============================================================
     void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

    }
```

In the `closeEvent` method trigger your signal:

```
void MyCustomWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
      emit WidgetClosed();
      event->accept();
}
```

Comment: I did that already, but for some reason that I might not have understood as well as I thought I´d have, my team-leader didn´t want it that way. But I´ll talk to him about that, seeing that other possible ways make much less sense.

Answer (score 0):

QWidget doesn't have many signals really, according to the documentation it has a grand total of 2. However, that doesn't mean you can't specify a signal yourself and use it, which is probably the best method.